# WCF data push to flash client without RTMP

Tags: android, iphone, wcf, flash

I am interested in connecting my android, iOS and flash clients to a wcf service and want to push updates to my clients from the WCF service as and when events regarding the client occurs.

From the google searches, i got weborb.net and flourinefx.net. But these are based on rtmp, so  i cant manage push for android and iphone clients.

Is there any alternative for pushing data from WCF service to all of my clients?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki). From what I've read it seems like it could do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i did not find any listener for flash client. Can you provide an alternative for that as well.